# How to combine all files in a directory, adding their individual file names as a new column in final merged file

Tags: linux, awk

I have a directory with files that looks like this:

```
CCG02-215-WGS.format.flt.txt
CCG05-707-WGS.format.flt.txt
CCG06-203-WGS.format.flt.txt
CCG04-967-WGS.format.flt.txt
CCG05-710-WGS.format.flt.txt
CCG06-215-WGS.format.flt.txt
```

Contents of each files look like this

```
1   9061390 14  93246140
1   58631131    2   31823410
1   108952511   3   110694548
1   168056494   19  23850376
etc...
```

Ideal output would be a file, let's call it all-samples.format.flt.txt, that would contain the concatenation of all files, but an additional column that displays which sample/file the row came from ( some minor formatting involved to remove the .format.flt.txt ):

```
1   9061390 14  93246140    CCG02-215-WGS
...
1   58631131    2   31823410    CCG05-707-WGS
...
1   108952511   3   110694548   CCG06-203-WGS
...
1   168056494   19  23850376    CCG04-967-WGS
```

Currently, I have the following code which works for individual files.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; split(ARGV[1],f,".")}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,f[1]}' CCG05-707-WGS.format.flt.txt

#OUTPUT

1   58631131    2   31823410    CCG05-707-WGS
...
```

However, when I try to apply it to all files, using the star, it adds the first filename it finds to all the files as the 4th column.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; split(ARGV[1],f,".")}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,f[1]}' *

#OUTPUT, 4th column should be as seen in previous code block

1   9061390 14  93246140    CCG02-215-WGS
...
1   58631131    2   31823410    CCG02-215-WGS
...
1   108952511   3   110694548   CCG02-215-WGS
...
1   168056494   19  23850376    CCG02-215-WGS
```

I feel like the solution may just lie in adding an additional parameter to awk... but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks!

*UPDATE*

Using OOTB awk var FILENAME solved the issue, plus some elegant formatting logic for the file names.

Thank @RavinderSingh13!

awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} FNR==1{file=FILENAME;sub(/..*/,"",file)} {print $0,file}' *.txt

Comment: You just want the `FILENAME` variable. `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $1, $2, $3, $4, FILENAME}' *` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. We need to use `FILENAME` OOTB variable here of `awk`. Then whenever there is first line of any txt file(all txt files passed to this program) then remove everything from `.` to till last of value and in main program printing current line followed by file(file's name as per requirement)

```bash
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
FNR==1{
  file=FILENAME
  sub(/\..*/,"",file)
}
{
  print $0,file
}
' *.txt
```

***OR*** in a one-liner form try following `awk` code:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} FNR==1{file=FILENAME;sub(/\..*/,"",file)} {print $0,file}' *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

Any version `awk`:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==1{split(FILENAME, a, /\./)} {print $0, a[1]}' *.txt
```

Or in gnu-awk:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' 'BEGINFILE{split(FILENAME, a, /\./)} {print $0, a[1]}' *.txt
```